# Streamlit - TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I'm trying to sort the index using the below line.

```
task_count_20.sort_index(ascending=False, ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
```

The above line of code is working in `Google colab` and in the local environment, but when I'm trying in building the app using `streamlit`, I'm getting the below traceback error.

```
TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'
Traceback:
File "app.py", line 601, in <module>
    Lollipop_count_plot(df, col, count=20)
File "app.py", line 209, in Lollipop_count_plot
    task_count_20.sort_index(ascending=False, ignore_index=True, inplace=True)#
```

[In the official pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), `sort_index()` has the keyword `ignore_index`

> pandas.DataFrame.sort_index

> DataFrame.sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', sort_remaining=True, ignore_index=False, key=None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the document, I found the `ignore_index` New in version 1.0.0.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

[image]

maybe you need check the `pandas` library version.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on codechef.com,

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
```

shows `0.23.4` which is before version `1.0.0` in which `ignore_index` first appeared in `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`.